# Laravel storage fake appears to be not working in github actions

Tags: github-actions, laravel-9

Locally everything works great:

```php
        Storage::fake('local');

        $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('watch.jpg');

        $watchData = [
            'model' => 'beatae unde adipisci',
            'size' => '50',
            'number' => 'm98300',
            'metal' => 'deserunt',
            'rrp' => '92840',
            'status' => 'discontinued',
            'brand_id' => '2',
            'new_image' => $file,
        ];

        $response = $this->post('/watch', $watchData);

        Storage::disk('local')->assertExists('mg/jc-int/watch-images/1.jpg');
```

When I try to run this same test as part of my deployment workflow in GitHub Actions:

```
1) Tests\Feature\WatchImagesTest::test_a_watch_image_can_be_created
Unable to find a file or directory at path [mg/jc-int/watch-images/1.jpg].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

I've tried a few things but I think this is more that I'm not understand how either `Storage::fake()` works or how GitHub actions handles filepaths?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

In my controller that handles the image upload, I'm grabbing a folder from my config:

```
$folder = config('site.DO_SUBFOLDER');
```

This value is taken from my `.env` and wasn't being included in the deployment pipeline.